# Problem with process creation

Tags: erlang

I am implementing a car park with 2 entry gates and 1 by which you can leave the park. For me, everything looks fine but I am getting errors like

```
Error in process <0.84.0> with exit value: {badarg,[{parking,car,2},{random,uniform,0}]}
```

My code is:

```
-module (parking2).
-export ([start/3]).
-export ([car/2, parkingLoop/1]).

carsInit(0, _Iterations) ->
    ok;
carsInit(Number, Iterations) ->
    spawn(parking, car, [Number, Iterations]),
    carsInit(Number - 1, Iterations).

car(_ID, 0) ->
    ok;
car(ID, Iterations) ->
    Gate = random:uniform(2),
    parking ! {enter, self()},
    receive
        error ->
            io:format("Car ~B ncanot enter - there is no free place.~n", [ID]),
            Time = random:uniform(1000),
            timer:sleep(Time),
            car(ID, Iterations);
        ok ->
            io:format("Car ~B entered through the ~B gate~n", [ID, Gate])
    end,
    StopTime = random:uniform(500) + 500,
    timer:sleep(StopTime),
        parking ! {leave, self(), ID},
        FreerideTime = random:uniform(1000) + 500,
    timer:sleep(FreerideTime),
    car(ID, Iterations - 1).

parkingInit(Slots) ->
    spawn(parking, parkingLoop, [Slots]).

parkingLoop(Slots) ->
    receive
        {enter, Pid} ->
            if Slots =:= 0 ->
                Pid ! error
            end,
            Pid ! ok,
            parkingLoop(Slots - 1);
        {leave, Pid, ID} ->
            io:format("Car ~B left the car park.", [ID]),
            parkingLoop(Slots + 1);
        stop ->
            ok
    end.    


start(Cars, Slots, Iterations) ->
    parkingInit(Slots),
    carsInit(Cars, Iterations).
```

May anybody help me ? I learn Erlang for a couple of days and have no idea, what's wrong here.

Thanks in advance,
Radek

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example you posted uses the wrong module in the `spawn/3` call:

```
spawn(parking, parkingLoop, [Slots]).
```

It should work better (or at least give a more up to date error) if you change this to:

```
spawn(?MODULE, parkingLoop, [Slots]).
```

(Always use `?MODULE`, which is a macro that evaluates to the current module name, when doing such things since it will avoid a lot of mistakes using the wrong module than intended).

The bug comes from not registering the `parkingLoop` process. You're trying to send a message to it using `parking ! ...` but no process is named `parking`. Change line 33 to:

```
register(parking, spawn(parking2, parkingLoop, [Slots])).
```

(Even here you can use the `?MODULE` macro to avoid problems in the future: `?MODULE ! ...` and `register(?MODULE, ...)` since you only have one process with this name)

Also, your `if` statement on line 38 misses a fall-through clause. Make it look like this to handle the case where `Slots` is *not* equal to zero:

```
if 
    Slots =:= 0 ->Pid ! error;
    true -> ok
end,
```

(The `ok` expression will have no effect since the return value of the `if` statement is not used)

Comment: Sorry that I am asking but how to do that?

Comment: Ah, no problem! :-) Just click the little green tick box under the answer votes to the left of the answer (and welcome to Stack Overflow!)